# ORA-01001: invalid cursor while using functions in Oracle SQL Developer?

Tags: oracle, function, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have created a function that has the Customer_id as input and returns a number that represents the total cost of orders for this customer. I have to multiply the Order_Qty from table order_details and the Unit_Price from table items to get the total cost of each order.

This is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION FIND_TOTAL
(CUSTOMER_ID_IN IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN NUMBER IS
ORDER_QTY_IN NUMBER;
UNIT_PRICE_IN NUMBER;
TOTAL_COST_OUT NUMBER;
CURSOR C1 IS
SELECT od.ORDER_QTY
FROM ORDER_DETAILS od JOIN ORDERS o 
ON od.ORDER_ID = o.ORDER_ID
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER_ID_IN;
CURSOR C2 IS
SELECT i.UNIT_PRICE
FROM ITEMS i JOIN ORDER_DETAILS od
ON i.ITEM_ID = od.ITEM_ID
JOIN ORDERS o 
ON o.ORDER_ID = od.ORDER_ID
WHERE CUSTOMER_ID = CUSTOMER_ID_IN;
BEGIN
    OPEN C1;
        FETCH C1 INTO UNIT_PRICE_IN;
        IF C1%FOUND AND C2%FOUND THEN
        TOTAL_COST_OUT := ORDER_QTY_IN*UNIT_PRICE_IN;
    END IF;
    CLOSE C1;
    CLOSE C2;
    RETURN TOTAL_COST_OUT;
END;
/
```

Now I have to use the function to write a select statement that selects all the customers and the total cost of the orders they have ever made.

```
SELECT CUSTOMER_ID, FIND_TOTAL(CUSTOMER_ID) AS TOTAL_COST
FROM CUSTOMERS;
```

But when I do this I get an error:

```
ORA-01001: invalid cursor
ORA-06512: at "TUG81959.FIND_TOTAL", line 22
01001. 00000 -  "invalid cursor"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Here's a list of my tables in case it is helpful:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you sould open and fecth C2 cursor before referencing C2%FOUND.

Let me know.

Regards,

Comment: You were right, I totally skipped C2 cursor. It's just one of those mistakes where you can't see it until someone points it out for you. Thanks!